# General linear group inclusion

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, orthogonal-matrices, general-linear-group

Do we have $\operatorname{GL}(n,F)\le \operatorname{O}(2n,F)$ where O means general orthogonal group and $F$ is an algebraically closed field?
I checked some finite group cases: $\operatorname{GL}(2,5)\le \operatorname{GOPlus}(4,5)$ and $\operatorname{GL}(3,5)\le \operatorname{GOPlus}(6,5)$. The inclusion was true.

Comment: This seems odd since $O(n,\mathbb{C})$ is compact and $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is open dense (and not compact). The "inclusion" you are stating (you should say injection) would have to be not continuous. Could you explicit the group injections you made?

Comment: Thank you for your input. What if we view them as algebraic groups?

Comment: I think you get such an embedding by letting $g \in {\rm GL}(n,F)$ act as $g$  on a totally singular $n$-dimensional subspace of the $2n$-dimensional orthogonal space, with $(g^{-1})^{\mathsf {T}}$ acting on a complementary totally singular subspace. This is a proper subgroup of a maximal parabolic subgroup. It is easiest to visualize if you use the antidiagonal $1$'s symmetric bilinear form rather than $I_{2n}$.

Comment: @julio: $O(n, \mathbb{C})$ is not compact. You're thinking of the unitary group.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan you’re right I had the real case in mind, mybad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Here is an abstract way to see this. If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$, we equip the direct sum $V \oplus V^{\ast}$ with the bilinear form

$$B(v_1 \oplus f_1, v_2 \oplus f_2) = f_1(v_2) + f_2(v_1).$$

This is a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form, and since it is defined using only natural operations it is preserved by the action of $GL(V)$, so we get an embedding $GL(V) \hookrightarrow O(V \oplus V^{\ast}, B)$.

Over a field containing $i$ (and having characteristic $\neq 2$), which includes $\mathbb{F}_5$, this form is equivalent to the standard symmetric bilinear form so we get the desired result. In general (again assuming the characteristic $\neq 2$) it's equivalent to the diagonal form with signature $(\dim V, \dim V)$.

Comment: yes, the characteristic is not 2. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, what are $f_1$ and $f_2$?

Comment: @scsnm: they're generic elements of the dual $V^{\ast} = \text{Hom}(V, K)$, thought of as linear functionals $f : V \to K$.

Comment: Similarly by defining the form as $f_1(v_2) - f_2(v_1)$, you get an embedding into the symplectic group.